# O que pode levar um automações Selenium não rodas em maquinas diferentes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Estou fazendo alguns robôs que fiz utilizando Selenium com a linguagem Python 3.7.0 - para fazer digitação em formulários, bom esse meu robô funciona perfeitamente rodando em minha maquina, da forma como eu espero. Porém é quando eu gero o .exe para executar esse código em outras maquinas, ele acaba quebrando me outros lugares onde não acontece na minha maquina, como por exemplo nesse fragmento de código

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="btn-aplicar-filtro"]')))
element.click()

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="caixas-status"]/div/div/div/div/div[2]')))
element.click()
```

onde algo simples ele acaba não encontrando ou errando o calculo de click.

Fiz vários testes mudando código a forma como ele encontra e sempre obtenho resultado diferentes em maquinas diferentes.

mas a questão em si é o que eu devo considerar na hora de fazer um código que devera rodar em maquinas diferentes usando a tecnologia do Selenium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muitas coisas como:

- Versão do navegador
- Velocidade do computador
- Velocidade da internet
- Versão do sistema operacional
- Comportamento do site

E muito mais coisas que não consigo pensar agora.

Para alguns desses itens, você consegue ter controle (Como versão do navegador ou sistema operacional. Para garantir um ambiente igual é possível rodar as coisas dentro do docker ou usando algum serviço terceiro como Browserstack), outros você pode aumentar o tempo de espera até cada elemento estiver visível.